# Auto-fill form not working with Bootstrap in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have two different forms, and I would like Form1 to be auto-filled depending on the value of Form2.
I thought my codes below should work, but it isn't. Does anyone see why?
The word "success" is shown on the console if I put `1000` in Form2, so this part is working fine. I expect to see `1000` in Form1 as well but it just stays empty.

```
<b-form-input
  id="price1"
  v-model="price1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="price1"
/>

<b-form-input
  id="price2"
  v-model="price2"
  type="text"
  placeholder="price2"
  @blur.native="calculatePrice1()"
/>
```

```
methods: {
  calculatePrice1 () {
    if (this.price2 <= 3000) {
      console.log('success')
      this.price1 = this.price2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are both `price1` and `price2` defined in your `data` function?

Comment: OMG `price1` was missing. It worked as expected after I added `price1` !!! You saved my day, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding both `price1` and `price2` in my `data` function solved the problem.